# WPF gridview button column disable only the button

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I need to disable gridview button only when data bind or button click because I need to disable that button for existing records only and when user add new record need to active my grid button.

here is my XAML code,

```
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Name="grdBtnAdd" Cursor="Hand"   Click="Button_Click_1" Width="20" Height="20" >

                                        <Button.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <Border Style="{StaticResource borstyle}" BorderBrush="#282828"  BorderThickness=".5" CornerRadius="3" Name="bor"  >

                                                    <Image Width="20" Height="18" Source="/Images\plus1.png"></Image>
                                                </Border>

                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Button.Template>
                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

please help me. I found how to disable button after click grid button. I need a way to disable grid buttons.

Comment: is there any way to find out weather the record is existing or new one.. like isnew property in the object..?
if so you can do this using data triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood the issue correctly than the following should work:

Bind the button IsEnabled property to a property in the viewModel.

```
<Button Name="grdBtnAdd" IsEnabled="{Binding IsNewRecordsAvailable}" Cursor="Hand" Click="Button_Click_1" Width="20" Height="20">
...
</Button>
```

Set the viewModel as the views' dataContext:

```
Sub New()
    Me.Datacontext = new viewModel
End Sub
```

The viewModel will implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and the property will look like this:

```
 Private m_isNewRecordsAvailable As Boolean
    Public Property IsNewRecordsAvailable() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_isNewRecordsAvailable
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            m_isNewRecordsAvailable = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsNewRecordsAvailable")
        End Set
    End Property
```

Now when you want to enable or disable the button , just set IsNewRecordsAvailable to true or false.

Here are some more examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/BindBetterINotifyProperty.aspx

Comment: Tx MichaleS implement INotifyPropertyChanged is the solution.